# Sort taxonomy terms alphabetically by default

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I created a taxonomy vocabulary and added some taxonomy terms to it. How can i sort alphabetically the listing of terms in taxonomy vocabulary page. The same sorting needs to reflect in content type fields when this vocabulary is added as term reference.

Comment: If default sorting is not good enough for you, why don't you switch to Views?

Comment: List the taxonomy, then 'reset to alphabetical'.

Comment: I need to remove rest to alphabetical button. Its drupal core vocabulary page. Do I need to edit drupal core term listing query.  Or any drupal hooks are available. On every addition of new term,the list need to sort alphabetically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hijacked the code from /modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.admin.inc that runs when you click "Reset to alphabetical". I tweaked it a bit and you can place this code in a custom module and it will run every time you insert a taxonomy term.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_taxonomy_term_insert()
 */
function YOURMODULE_taxonomy_term_insert($term) {

  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($term->vid);
  $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid);

  if($vocabulary->machine_name = 'MACHINE_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_FORCE_ORDERING') {
    //Make sure the taxonomy doesn't have terms with two parents
    if ($vocabulary->hierarchy < 2 && count($tree) > 1) {
      $params = array(
        'values' => array(
          'vid' => $term->vid, 
          'name' => $vocabulary->name, 
          'machine_name' => $vocabulary->machine_name, 
        ), 
      );

      taxonomy_vocabulary_confirm_reset_alphabetical_submit(NULL, $params);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want it to apply to all vocabularies, you can remove the IF statement on line 7. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simply scroll to bottom and click on reset alphabetical at /admin/structure/taxonomy/, do that after doing changes, you maybe be able to have a cron run and do this every few hours or so.